# Got error Can't get hostname for your address

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with the `mysql_connect` function. When I try it I get:

> Can't get hostname for your address

Then I tried Googling the error and I found the answered to put
skip-name-resolve is in the my `.ini` configuration file under [mysqld].

After I set it, this error still happen.
Anyone have another way how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, could you give us the line you use to call mysql_connect? Just remove your username and password, please.

Comment: One of the tags in your post is MySQL error 1064, which is actually a syntax error. Did you mean to add that tag?

Comment: @kavi Siegel: 
define("DB_HOST", "ABC");
define("DB_USERNAME", "ABC");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "ABC@@0");
define("DB_NAME", "ABC");

previously its working normaly. but i dont know what it happen today.

Comment: @djdy : yup. its the same error. i tried to solve this error based on their suggestion. but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

First issue Fariezza, if you're just starting a new script: do not use mysql_connect. Switch to PDO or MySQLi.

Secondly, with no code, comes no debug or advice. if you're going to request assistance, we need the code.

Last but not least, when doing DB queries, I've found it best to simply DEFINE your SQL Database, Username and Password in a single config.php file, include that file and then call the DB connection. You'll be able to use .htaccess later on to prevent simple http access to the config file whilst ensuring that it's chmod readable to all your other scripts.

Addendum:

Ok.. let's start your code again;

Config.php

```
Define('DB_SERVER', '<server>');
Define('DB_NAME', '<database_name>');
Define('DB_USERNAME', '<database_username>');
Define('DB_PASSWORD', '<database_password>');
```

Database.php

```
require_once('Config.php');
class dbConn {
   function __construct() {
      $this->db_conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
      if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
          echo '(<p>Unable to connect to database</p><p>' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '</p>)';
      }
   }
}
```

Now then; that'll both get your config right, connect to the database (dbConn) and allow you to do a database query later on through mysqli.

Please stop using mysql, you'll thank me in future - although PDO is a great alternative to MySQLi if you're thinking of moving away from MySQL at a later date.

Comment: thnks for ur answer and kindness. but i'm a bit confius. why previously its can working. is it have any conflict?

Comment: What's your mysql_connect line?

Comment: $DB_obj = new Mysql();

if($DB_obj->db_Connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)){
 
}else{
 
}

print $DB_obj->dbError();

Comment: thnks John..Really appreciate your help and attention.